# Allocating an array of strings in external function

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I am trying to allocate an array of string, via another function. I'm able to do that in main, but when I tried it in another function (adding another level of pointing) I got stuck.

This is the code:

```
int main() {

    char** book;

    FillBook( &book );
    ...
    ...

}
```

Now I try to allocate memory for 5 strings of 3 letters, and fill them, but I get stuck (the program execution stops):

```
void FillBook( char*** book_pt ) {

    *book_pt = malloc( 5 * sizeof( char* ) ); //this is where I make space for 5 strings

    *book_pt[0] = malloc( 5 * sizeof( char ) ); //this one works
    strcpy(*book_pt[0], "ok"); 

    *book_pt[1] = malloc( 5 * sizeof( char ) ); //this one doesn't and the execution stops here
    strcpy(*book_pt[1], "no"); 

    return;
}
```

Every pointer I try to allocate after the *book_pt[0] produces the same effect.
It also does the same thing using strdup.

Adding the line:

```
(*book_pt == NULL)
```

after the first malloc shows that it does not return a NULL value.

Comment: I think you need `(*book_pt)[1] = `. Check [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 3):

The expressions using the variable `char*** book_pt` are missing parenthesis that change precedence.

For example:

```
*book_pt[1]
```

should be:

```
(*book_pt)[1]
```

Without parenthesis [] operator takes precedence over the * operator, but you need to dereference `book_pt` first.

Your `*book_pt[0]` happens to work, but that's just because `book_pt[0]` is the same as `*book_pt`. But when an index `i` is anything besides 0, `*book_pt[i]` is *different* than `(*book_pt)[i]`.

Comment: Well, for 0 index it's equivalent. The problem is `*book_pt[1]`

Comment: thank you, it really looks like I didn't spend much time trying before asking, but I actually did, thank you again

Comment: @MatthewGunn Feel free to improve the answer.

Comment: For this reason, I prefer `1[*book_pt]` - it neatly avoids the ambiguity